# Cannot load a Floppy Disk image with Bochs emulator

Tags: emulation

I have a floppy disk image which I am trying to load with Bochs Emulator.

It is from a CTF challenge and can be downloaded from here: http://squarectf.com/2017/floppy.img

I am using Bochs version 2.3.9 on Windows 7 x64

I started Bochs.exe and configured the memory and disk settings as shown below:

Memory options:

[image]

Disk and Boot options:

[image]

However, when I start the emulator, it gives the following error:

[image]

I have seen a writeup online for this CTF that describes the same method for loading the disk image and it worked.

Please let me know why it does not work for me.

Note: I am able to load the disk image using qemu-system-x86_64 or qemu-system-i386 on Linux already. However, I want to understand why I cannot load it with Bochs.

I even tried the method of creating a bochsrc file and loading it using bochsdbg.exe as shown below:

```
bochsdbg.exe -f bochsrc -q
```

However, I still get an error while loading it.

**Update:** I am able to load the image in Bochs emulator by selecting floppy as the boot device under Boot options.

However, I cannot load the image using bochsdbg.exe. Below is my bochsrc.txt file:

```
romimage: file=$BXSHARE/BIOS-bochs-latest
vgaromimage: file=$BXSHARE/VGABIOS-lgpl-latest
megs: 16
ata0: enabled=1, ioaddr1=0x1f0, ioaddr2=0x3f0, irq=14
ata0-master: type=disk, path="floppy.img", mode=flat, cylinders=2, heads=16, spt=63
boot: floppy
```

And I get the following error message:

```
Bochs is exiting with the following message:
[      ] bochsrc.txt:5: ataX-master/slave: unknown type 'floppy'
```

The reason I want to have a proper bochsrc file is because I want to use IDA Pro to debug the boot sector.

Comment: Looks like its trying to boot from the Hard Drive. Check the boot options in bochs. This [image](https://emaculation.com/lib/exe/fetch.php/bochsdiskoptions3.png).

Comment: @0xec Thanks. I am able to load the image in Bochs emulator now. I selected floppy as the boot option. Now, I have another question. While I am able to get it working using the Bochs GUI, I still cannot get it to load properly using bochsdbg.exe. I have updated my question with my bochsrc file. Please have a look and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Your bochsrc is incorrect. `ata` is for the hard disk. Should rather be `floppya`. Have a look [here](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/bochsrc.html) under *Section 4.3.19. floppya/floppyb*

Answer (score 1):

I fought a similar error for a while and figured I was naming the disk image as `disk.img`. When I renamed it to something else, it worked. In your example, you're naming it to `floppy.img`, so you could try something else.

It's a bit of a guess, but seems like bochs doesn't like files with reserved words, like disk or floppy.